# Determine an equation for the tangent to the graph of f(x) at point P.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, graphing-functions

Determine an equation for the tangent to the graph of *f*(x) at point P.

Use of CAS tool allowed.

`a) f(x)=  3/(1+√x)`   ,  *P*(4, 1)

---

`b) f(x)= √(5-x^2 )` ,  *P*(1, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are allowed to use a CAS tool, there is not much to do here.

Here is one such tool: [a)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+line+to+3%2F%281%2BSqrt%5Bx%5D%29+at+4), and [b)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+line+to+Sqrt%5B5-x%5E2%5D+at+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Equation of tangent line of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$ where

a) $x_0=4,y_0=1$ and $m=f'(4)$

b) $x_0=1,y_0=2$ and $m=f'(1)$